# Regex match optional set of characters not working

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to capture the username from these lines:

```
title="user1 is online now"><b><font color="#2568BA"><b>user1</b></font></b></a>
title="user2 is online now"><b>user2</b></a>
```

With this as the pattern:

```
title=".{1,16} is \w{5,8}? now"><b>(?:<font color="#\w{6}">)<b>(?<text>.+?)</b>(?:</font>)</b></a>?
```

But it's only capturing user1.
The "font color" tag needs to be ignored, sometimes it's there sometimes it's not.

I'm struggling with this for hours now, what am I missing?

Comment: Why are you bothering with anything after the `title=".{1,16} is \w{5,8}? now"`?

Comment: [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/590747/1324033)

Comment: @Rawling, because it will match too many of the same username. What I pasted was just a fraction of a html source page.

Comment: How are you currently getting/parsing the HTML? I guess you are doing it with some sort of HTML parser, aren't you?

Comment: @Sayse, not parsing anything, just messing around with regex with html

Comment: Why not just `(?<=title=")\S+` ?  Or, if you want a capturing group:  `title="(?<UserName>\S+)`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, because the group I want to catch is between the `<b></b>` tag where you see the group `(?<text>.+?)`.

Comment: Will it always be the same as the username that follows `title=`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, yes, but because it matches the same user 3 times, I had to look for something unique and make the match only occur once. Therefore I had to make the matching string a bit longer.

Comment: I don't understand.  In the examples you posted, my suggestion matches only the user name that follows `Title=`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93683/discussion-between-quoter-and-ron-rosenfeld).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might work.

- Assume that username follows `title="` and is followed by `is on(or off)line`
- capture that instance into capturing group 1
- use a back reference to find the last instance of username in the line
- capture that into named capturing group `UserName`

---

```
title="(\S+)(?= is (?:on|off)line).*(?<UserName>\k<1>)
```

If you wanted to, you could also capture the on or off line status.

Answer (score 0):

For those examples this should work:

```
title="\S+\sis\s(?:on|off)line\snow">(?:<b><font[^>]+>)?<b>(.*?)</b>
```

Comment: Small suggestion:  You could replace `[^\s]+` with `\S+`  I think that works in c#

Comment: Cheers I've put that in.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following regex:

```
<[^>]*>(user\d+)<[^>]*>
```

Comment: That matches everything between `<>`. That's not what I want.

Comment: The word 'user' was just an example, none of the usernames actually are 'user' or start with 'user'. In fact 'user' is just random, it could be even Mayur.